# VBA replace comma with line break in word?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to replace commas in an address with a new line break using the below code:

```
Replace(Range("P" & ActiveCell.Row).Value, ",", Chr(10))
```

But in Word this produces a weird ? symbol rather than put each bit of text on a new line.

[image]

Can someone please show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: `vbcrlf` instead of `chr(10)` ?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav  this seems to add the line break but still has a ? proceeding each line

Comment: what is it in Word, a bullet point or something, can you show that pls/

Comment: @Nathan_Sav please see updated answer

Comment: can you show the excel contents? also

Comment: Wouldn't the `Word` replacement be:  `ActiveDocument.Content.Find.Execute FindText:=",", ReplaceWith:=Chr(11)` or have I read this wrong and you do the replacement in `Excel` and then copy/paste to `Word`?

Comment: I am reading it as `word.location = replacing(excel.contents)`